# Celsius to Fahrenheit back and forth conversion with rounding.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

Recently I've encountered some problem with conversion Celsius and Fahrenheit scales. 
Let's assume that I have value of 44 degrees in Fahrenheit scale, I convert this to the Celsius which gives me 6,6667 degrees in Celsius. I'm rounding it to the 7 degrees. Then I'm incrementing value from 44 to the 45 degrees and converting it to the Celsius once more time, it gives me 7,2222. I'm rounding this once again and I receive 7 Celsius degrees as before.

My question is there any algorithm to avoid ambiguous rounding results for integers? Maybe different method of rounding can be applied ? Maybe some additional scale can be applied ? If there is no such a algorithm, what is minimum precision in the Celsius scale to provide not ambiguous conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $1{}^\circ {\rm F}$ in difference of two temperatures corresdonds to $\frac 59{}^\circ {\rm C}$, ambiguity in rounding to integer cannot be avoided: For the interval $32{}^\circ {\rm F}$ - $41{}^\circ{\rm F}$ is mapped to $0{}^\circ$ - $5{}^\circ{\rm C}$. You can avoid ambiguity if you round for example to $0.5{}^\circ{\rm C}$, as $\frac 12 < \frac 59$.